# App throwing up EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1, address = 0xa0000008) on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

my app is compiling fine on iPhone however when I try and compile it on iPad it throws the error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 1, address = 0xa0000008)

At this point in my code:

```
[self addChild:settings z:2];
```

No idea why this is happening... anybody?

mainMenu.m:

```
#import "mainMenu.h"
#import "gameData.h"
#import "gameDataParser.h"

BOOL settingsOut;

@implementation mainMenu

@synthesize iPad;


- (id)init{

if( (self=[super init])) {

    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    mainMenu *menuLayer = [[mainMenu alloc] autorelease];
    [self addChild:menuLayer];

    settingsMenu *settings = [settingsMenu node]; <----- app breaks at breakpoint here
    [self addChild:settings z:2];                 <----- receive error if breakpoint here

    _settings = settings; 
    settingsOut = FALSE;

    CGPoint offScreenPoint = ccp(screenSize.width+(screenSize.width/2), 0);

    settings.position = offScreenPoint;

    // gameData *gameData = [gameDataParser loadData];

    // [gameDataParser saveData:gameData];

    self.iPad = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;


    if (screenSize.height > 490){
        CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mainBackgroundiPhoneFive.png"];
        background.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:background];
    }

    else{
        CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mainBackground.png"];
        background.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:background];
    }


    [self addButtons: screenSize.height];


}
return self;
}
```

mainMenu.h:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "SceneManager.h"
#import "settingsMenu.h"

extern BOOL settingsOut;

@interface mainMenu : CCScene {

    CCLayer * _settings;
    CCMenu * _play;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL iPad;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLayer *settings;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCMenu *play;

- (void) addButtons: (int) screenSize;

@end
```

settingsMenu.h:

```
#import "gameData.h"
#import "gameDataParser.h"
#import "cocos2d.h"


@interface settingsMenu : CCLayer {
CCMenuItem *_musicOn;
CCMenuItem *_musicOff;
CCMenuItem *_invertControlsOn;
CCMenuItem *_invertControlsOff;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL iPad;


@end
```

settingsMenu.m

```
#import "settingsMenu.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#import "mainMenu.h"
#import "sceneManager.h"

BOOL settingsOut;

@implementation settingsMenu

- (id)init{
    if((self=[super init])) {

    // Determine Screen Size
    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    self.iPad = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;

    if (screenSize.height > 490){
        CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"settingsiPhoneFive.png"];
        background.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:background];
    }

    else{
        CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"settings.png"];
        background.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:background];
    }
    [self addButtons];

}
return self;
}
```

Comment: You need to show quite a bit more code than that. Probably `settings` (or less likely `self`) are pointing to an invalid address, but that's impossible to tell from one code line and without a stack trace. Easiest is for you to break on that line using the debugger and verify all values before executing the line.

Comment: Perhaps settings is nil? Set a breakpoint and check.

Comment: Would either of these be reasons for it to only not compile on the iPad? I shall add some more code...

Comment: Dammmit posting all of that has made me realise... at least I think it is, problem is I've got it set on `if screenSize.height > 490` and then used an image in there which I haven't included in the project yet, I need to change the if statement to `if (!self.iPad && screenSize.height > 490)` that is the correct syntax for objective-c right?

Comment: Yes problem is still at large. It's almost definitely something to do with passing the settingsMenu layer to the mainMenu scene.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A strange solution has been found for this by myself, changing something in the code after the final breakpoint caused the code to be fixed, in mainMenu.m I changed the if statement: `if (screenSize.height > 490)` to `if (!self.iPad && screenSize.height > 490)` for the same reason I changed it in the settingsMenu.m (because I realised that my code for detecting the iPhone 5 also detected the iPad) and this has seemed to have fixed my problem, strangely!